# Stretch heightmap over whole plane

Tags: texturing, modifiers

**How do I stretch my heightmap over the whole plane?**

My plane has the dimensions of 6000 x 6000 and I subdivided it so that each pixel should be the value of one rectangle. My heightmap comes with 200 x 200px resolution.

I imported the image as texture, set the 'color space' to 'linear' and the clipped it.

[image: texture heightmap]

Now I added the modifier [**Displace**](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/displace.html) but it only interprets the values on a little area in the middle of the plane.

**How do I stretch my heightmap over the whole plane?**

[image: heightmap displace]
[image: blender edit mode and uv image mode]

**The result should be like that**
[image: example result]

Comment: Could you show your UV unwrap of the plane?

Comment: also, doing this would use 30x30 mesh pixels to represent 1x1 image pixel, are you sure that is the mesh resolution you wish?

Comment: @Carlo: I'm not totally sure how I do that?! I selected the plane and hit `Shift+f10` right?
@m.ardito: Yes, will smoothen the mesh later. But the elevation model has just a resolution of 30x30m

Comment: I did it some how before (http://i.imgur.com/JYkOc05.png), but I can't reprocess it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this also by hand, but one easy way would be  to use the `import images as planes` (included but not enabled by default), importing your "map".

You will get a plane with the same aspect ratio as your "map", of just 4 vertices, with the uv mapping already done. Just subdivide the plane 200 times (cuts, 6000/200=30), and apply displace modifier.

If using blender render, you can displace directly selecting the already imported "map" from the list. With cycles, the displace modifier only uses  a texture, but there is a button (see image below) in the modifier to "show the texture in the texture tab" where you can set the texture to image, and select your "map".

then in the modifier set it to use "uv coordinates"

cycles example:

[image]

blender render (internal) example:

[image]